# $e_1,e_2,e_3$ is an $\textrm{ON}^+$ basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $\angle u,e_1=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\angle u,e_2=\frac{\pi}{3}$. Determine $\angle u,e_3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, angle

I know that

$$
\cos \theta = \frac{u\cdot e_3}{|u|}
$$

but since I neither have any coordinates or the length of $u$, I don't think I can use this. Using the same formula for $u$ on $e_1$ and $e_2$ doesn't help me either. When I first saw it I thougt it'd be simple, just like in $\mathbb{R^2}$, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Since $e_{1}$, $e_{2}$, $e_{3}$ are a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ we may write:

$$u = a e_{1} + b e_{2} + c e_{3}$$

for some $a, b, c$ in the reals. To find these coefficients, note the property $ e_{i} \cdot e_{j}$ equals $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise. Multiply the above equation by $e_{1}$ to get:
$a_{1}=u \cdot e_{1}$

Generalizing to find all coefficients gives:

\begin{align}
u &= (u \cdot e_{1}) e_{1} + (u \cdot e_{2}) e_{2}  + (u \cdot e_{3}) e_{3} \\
  &= \| u \| \big( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} e_{1} +  \frac{1}{2} e_{2}  +  \cos(x) e_{3}\big)
\end{align}

Where $x$ is the angle we're after. Taking the square norm on both sides we get:

$$ \|u\|^2 = \| u \|^2 \big(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cos(x)^2\big)$$

Thus $1 = \frac{3}{4} + \cos(x)^2 $, $x = \frac{1}{3}\pi$ or $\frac{5}{3}\pi $

I believe (intuitively) you can also assume WLOG that the basis $\left \{ e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3} \right \}$ is the standard basis, and that $u$ has unit length, but that might require a more lengthy justification than the above.

Comment: Since $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is an ONB we can linearly map it onto the standard basis via an orthogonal transform $T$. Such transformations preserve angles: $\langle Tu| Tv\rangle = \langle u|v\rangle$ for any $u,v$. In particular $\langle u| e_1 \rangle = \langle Tu| T e_1\rangle = \langle \hat u |\hat e_1\rangle$. So yes one can w.l.o.g. assume the given ONB is the standard basis.